# Scala function does not return a value

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I think I understand the rules of implicit returns but I can't figure out why splithead is not being set. This code is run via

```
val m = new TaxiModel(sc, file)
```

and then I expect

```
m.splithead
```

to give me an array strings. Note head is an array of strings.

```
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
import org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD

class TaxiModel(sc: SparkContext, dat: String) {
  val rawData = sc.textFile(dat)

  val head = rawData.take(10)
  val splithead = head.slice(1,11).foreach(splitData)

  def splitData(dat: String): Array[String] = {
    val splits = dat.split("\",\"")
    val split0 = splits(0).substring(1, splits(0).length)
    val split8 = splits(8).substring(0, splits(8).length - 1)
    Array(split0).union(splits.slice(1, 8)).union(Array(split8))
  }
}
```

Comment: When you're unsure of what you've written, add explicit type information (`val slithead: Array[String] = ...`) and let the compiler tell you what you've done wrong.

Comment: `s/Scala function/Your function/`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`foreach` just evaluates expression, and do not collect any data while iterating. You probably need `map` or `flatMap` (see docs [here](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.10.3/index.html#scala.Array))

```
head.slice(1,11).map(splitData) // gives you Array[Array[String]]

head.slice(1,11).flatMap(splitData) // gives you Array[String]
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider also a for comprehension (which *desugars* in this case into `flatMap`),

```
for (s <- head.slice(1,11)) yield splitData(s)
```

Note also that Scala strings are equipped with ordered collections methods, thus

```
splits(0).substring(1, splits(0).length)
```

proves equivalent to any of the following

```
splits(0).drop(1)
splits(0).tail
```